# What's the differences between -m32, -m64, and nothing in gcc's options?

Tags: gcc, compiler-options

```
gcc -m32 main.cpp

gcc -m64 main.cpp

gcc main.cpp
```

What's the differences between `-m32`, `-m64`, and `nothing` in gcc's options?

Comment: You can run `man gcc` to find the answer, or [read here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html). The default flag used is determined by how the compiler was configured when built, usually implying *-m64* for 64-bit environments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Refer to gcc Manual Page [[here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)], it indicates

```
-m32 -m64 Generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment. 

The 32-bit environment sets int, long and pointer to 32 bits and 
generates code that runs on any i386 system. 

The 64-bit environment sets int to 32 bits and long and pointer to 
64 bits and generates code for AMD 's x86-64 architecture. 
For darwin only the -m64 option turns off the -fno-pic and -mdynamic-no-pic options.
```

Comment: And I'm assuming that nothing means it just defaults to whatever the local system's architecture is?